# L293D DC motor affecting LCD display

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, lcd, arduino-uno, l293d

In the circuit below, I have noticed that when the DC motor (`12V`) is disconnected, everything works nice. The LCD correctly displays what arduino sends to it. But when I connect the motor as indicated and the arduino sets `EN12` to `HIGH` and `1A` to high (`2A` being `LOW`) and the motor starts, the display suddenly overwrites some of the fields with weird symbols (see the second picture). This continues even after the motor is stopped and the number of rewritten fields increases everytime the motor starts (arduino no longer manages to overwrite those fields).

I thought that `L293D` should isolated the circuit with the motor. I even measured the current coming from arduino into the breadboard and there was no obvious change or increased draw due to motor starting (i don't even know why there should be but I was trying to figure that out).

Is there a mistake in the circuit?

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add a schematic.

Comment: 1) The L293, L298, etc are notoriously horrible. 2) Please use a schematic not a rendering, no one wants to look up the pinouts to see if you mixed up the two power supplies to the L293 3) You give no indication where the Arduino or LCD power are coming from 4) Placing a small capacitor across the motor brushes is routine, sometimes even more is done.

Comment: You're Fritzing wiring drawing (=/= schematic) doesn't contain the power supplies. Do draw them as well and reconsider if the circuits are isolated.

Comment: power the motor separately.

Comment: You are getting noise into your display data. Motor should be powered through a common mode choke of 100uH, and a 10uF bypass capacitor at the motor power terminals. Breadboards are terrible at isolating noise.

Comment: @Huisman I added the schematics. The power to Arduino board is provided by a 12V Power supply to the Arduino barrel connector (note that in the schematics, this is connected to Arduino Vin and Gnd since there was nowhere else to put it in the predefined shape). The same power supply also supplies the the L293D VCC2 (8th pin). So the circuits share ground (which however I think should be) and they also share the power supply but I would think all noise there would be filtered by Arduino and should not affect the digital pins.

Comment: BTW, when measuring voltage drop accross the 220ohm resistor, the lcd also generated some weird characters (but that might have some connection since it is breadboard, not soldered and the LCD is extremely sensitive to any "vibration")

Comment: If your schematic is to be believed, you have parts of your system only grounded *through* the L293 IC itself!  You should connect all the L293 grounds together, and provide distinct runs back to the power supply for logic and motor loads.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What exactly do you mean? I cannot see that something would not be connected to common ground.

Comment: Your LCD is connected only to L293 pin 12 and your RTC is connected only to L293 pin 5.  Their only connection to the power supply or arduino ground is through the L293 chip itself.  Either that, or your schematic does not represent what you built.  Worse, in your rendering the Arduino has no power, power ground, or signal ground connections *at all*.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Oh yes, you are right, that was a mistake in the drawing, I apollogize. The corrected version is uploaded including a corrected rendering. In the schema, the power supply is now connected to arduino board where the barrel jack would be. Otherwise, arduino ground is connected to the common ground, which I omitted in the previous schema. In the rendering, there are batteries but in reality it is a 12V DC power supply.

Comment: To be honest, this is still a wiring diagram, but more a black/white variant. A good schematic is readable, you see almost in one glance how everything is connected and you don't need to follow each net from start to end to find out how it is connected.

Comment: The motor is producing high frequent noise. Bluntly said, this noise is conducted by the motor wires, back through the L293, through the L293's supply wires back to the battery connector and proceeds through the supply wires to the Arduino and LCD display.

Comment: Regarding *"I thought that L293D should isolated the circuit with the motor"*: The Arduino, LCD display and motor (driver) share the same ground and battery voltage, so they are not isolated by definition.

Comment: @Huisman I added a hand drawn (what I think to be) schematic, i cannot do any better, I am not experienced in these drawings nor advanced circuitry drawing. The LCD is displayed as a bulb with a resistor since I have no idea how to draw such a complex connection...

Comment: Now you show the motor power supply and ground return as running *through* the Arduino, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You're suffering from really bad ground loops.  Basically, you've carefully arranged things so that all of the hash that the motor generates is forced to travel through a ground wire that should be providing a nice 0V reference to all of the digital bits.  This means that one thing's ground is not another thing's ground.

Draw a dotted line through the schematic.  On one side, put the motor, battery, and driver.  On the other side, put all the sensitive digital stuff.  Connect the motor-side and digital-side ground at exactly one point on the schematic.  Connect the motor-side and digital-side +12V at exactly one point on the schematic (the suggested choke isn't a bad idea, but it may not be necessary -- getting the wiring right is).

Now connect your circuit the same way.  **One** point on ground that is common to both circuits; **one** point on +12V that is common to both circuits.  **No** possible path for the motor current to flow back to the battery that includes the processor, clock, or display.

See if that helps.

[image]

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean, since if I use l293d, I do not see how to avoid the common ground. I am on a breadboard and it is not possible to make a single point to which I would solder all grounds, if this is what you mean. Just the LCD has 4 connection to ground so that is 4 holes on a breadboard. Can you please elaborate on what you mean in your reply?

Comment: I may understand what you mean (take all grounds to equipment and connect them to - on battery and take all +12V and connect them to +on battery), but I do not think that is realizable. If I power arduino with 12V, I have to use the barrel jack and thus this ground is already "unseparable" and I do not know of a simple way to connect Arduino to 12V without the barrel jack (I am not sure if Vin input will be able to handle that).

Comment: Then pick your motor ground and +12V off at the barrel jack.  Or pick the barrel jack off at the motor connection.

Comment: but this is essentially what I have one jack is split into two, I think you can see it in the photo in the question. Could this also be connected to the fact that even when nothing is supplied to VCC2 of l293d, there is non zero voltage accross the driver outputs  (1,2Y) and I can actually power an LED without VCC2, the LED is dimmed and so the power has to be supplied somehow by arduino.

Comment: Not according to your fritzing diagram.  You have the battery ground going to the driver chip and to the jack, and then you have the driver chip's ground going to the bread-board ground.

Comment: So that ground from the jack should be directly connected to the dc motor or not connected at all? I thought that, since according to the l293d datasheet, all grounds are connected, this would provide the common ground.

Comment: The important thing is that there should not be a possible ground path that is common between two digital things (i.e., the processor and the display, or different bits on the processor board), and that has motor current flowing in it.  Google "ground loop".  The only time and place in the universe where a wire has absolutely zero impedance from end to end is when it is a line on a schematic.  If you have nasty dirty spiky motor current traveling on a wire between digital elements then you will have nasty dirty spiky voltages between them, where you want the voltage to be essentially zero.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using some capacitors to reduce motor noise.

**At the motor**
First, place capacitors at the motor terminals as already suggested by @ChrisStratton. One 100nF 50V across the terminals and if possible from each terminal to the housing. The capacitors (partly) short the high frequent noise the motor generates.
Check [Dealing with Motor Noise](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J15/9) how to solder the capacitors. Apply other tips as well (like twisting motor and supply wires).

**At the L293D**
Add a 100nF and a 10uF to 100uF elco (rated *twice* or more your battery voltage) to the Vcc2 input of the L293D as shown in the schematic and a 100nF at the Vcc1.
The capacitors should have leads as short as possible (they are drawn larger for clarity). The order of placing the capacitors matters. The 100nF should be closest to Vcc2 and GND, the elco second closest, the red/black supply wires third closest.
Peak currents drawn by the L293D and motor will now be drawn from these capacitors, reducing noise and keeping your ground signal better at zero volt.

**At the LCD and RTC module**
I'm not sure whether the LCD and RTC module have their own decoupling capacitors, but it can't do harm adding a 100nF at the power supply of both. (I didn't draw one for the RTC module).

**On the breadboard**
You can supply the Arduino at VIN on the POWER connector instead of the jack connector. Connecting at like drawn in the wiring diagram, you get star points for power and ground @TimWescott is referring to (shown as circles in the framed wiring diagram).

I assume you use the regulated 5V from the regulator on the Arduino board to power the LCD, the RTC module and the VCC1 of the L293D. (It is not drawn in coloured Fritzing wiring diagram and you shouldn't indicate it as a 5V battery in the schematic).

Where the 5V and GND wires enter your breadboard, put a 10uF capacitor next to it.
Order is important again. So, first 5V/GND wires, left of it the elco, left of the elco all other connections to the 5V/GND. See wiring diagram below.

[image]

NB. Pictures of and values on shown capacitors are illustrative.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvonT3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NB. Schematic is partially drawn in order to indicate the capacitors.